Produce a result using partial match from data within a specified cell
I am looking to pull the name of a customer from the tab "Contact_Data" based on a partial match to the data in column C of the tab "Chart_Graph". I will be using this later to produce reports that show the last time a specific customer was contacted, but this is the key piece to getting to that point. Right now I need to focus on solving this equation first.
Please see link to the sample sheet that I have created.
Access Sample Sheet
I have attempted to be as detailed as possible and this issues impacts a very important project I am working on. I would ask that you please ask me questions before simply closing this question as that makes this process much more difficult than it needs to be and I am checking back frequently so I will be responsive.
I have tried FILTER combined with FIND, SEARCH, REGEXMATCH, and I have tried VLOOKUP which is what is in the sample sheet in Column D. All produce some results but not all. Changing FALSE to TRUE, produces results, but 98% incorrect results.
The formula in the sheet currently which produces SOME results in column D: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2&"*",Contact_Data!$A:$A,1,FALSE)," ")
if TRUE produces mostly incorrect resuts: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2&"*",Contact_Data!$A:$A,1,TRUE)," ")
I have also tried with no success: =FILTER(Contact_Data!A:A, FIND(C2, Contact_Data!A:A)) =FILTER(Contact_Data!A:A, REGEXMATCH(Contact_Data!A:A,C2))
The following formula works until I pull it down the column, then it only works in the last cell because it spills over. I do not know how to limit it to 1 response in the cell where the formula is contained. See column G =FILTER(Contact_Data!A:A, SEARCH(Contact_Data!A:A,C2)) Error produced when expanding: "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in G4."
I have also tried using QUERY. I again get some results, but it is not working to produce a result in each cell in the column where there is data to test in Column C and it should be able to. Please see column F:
=QUERY(Contact_Data!A:C, "select A where A contains '"&SPLIT(C2, ",")&"'", 0)
**So I need one of three solutions: **
Column D - VLOOKUP that produces a consistent result. Pulling the correct name from the Contact Data Tab, column A that partially matches the same embedded within the notes in Chart_Graph column C.
OR
Column E - Filter(Search that allows the formula to produce a result in each cell in column E based on the partial name in column C.
OR
Column F - Query that is able to produce an accurate result in each cell in the range where data exists in column C


Here's one approach you may test out:
=map(C2:index(C:C,match(,0/(C:C<>""))),lambda(Σ,let(y,split(Σ," "),x,counta(y),Λ,tocol(Contact_Data!A2:A,1),iferror(+torow(
 reduce(,sequence(x,1,x,-1),lambda(a,c,hstack(a,xlookup("*"&join(" ",choosecols(y,sequence(c)))&"*",Λ,Λ,,2)))),1),"--"))))


backend logic:

pick one word at a time from the range C2:C22 using map/lambda →
lets go with Jason Rye Sample → splits them to know we have 3
words here → then it uses wildcard lookup search for the full word
(Jason Rye Sample) as first iteration  → for second iteration it
goes with Jason Rye → for third iteration, it searches for
Jason → finally it filters the first possible match which we would've obtained in second iteration
the above logic is used since a direct single word like Jason could match with Jason Rye or Jason Statham(if present in Contact_Data list) while ideally a multiple word match would reveal that Jason Rye has a full name_match available in Contact_Data
Also one thing to note is that your test data has names at the start of Event Title alike Jason Rye Sample, for which the formula is designed. If your real data set has a scenario where the names could be in the midst like Hello Jason Rye Sample, then formula would need further adjustments to fit in those new scenarios as well!


Amazing! Would you mind at all providing me a bit of explanation on how this formula works. I am trying to learn and I will take the time to look up the various functions used within this solution, but if you could break it down a bit, if you have time, prior to me closing the question, that would be very very helpful in my learning journey. Thanks so much!

Added some basic possible explanation part to the answer

the formula by default auto-fills the column since its array-enabled; any specific reason to opt for script again?!

Hello, I applied this to my actual data and have had a few mismatches occur. Wondering if you have any ideas to solve? All are customer names, but being mistaken for the wrong customer name. Jason Mills (Entry in Column C)  = Jason Greydanus (Name produced by formula from Contact Data), John Kroondijk sample (Entry in Column C) = Dave Johnson (Name produced by formula from Contact Data),  Harry Vandennieuwlaar (Entry in Column C)= Harry & Ryan Dykxhoorn (Name produced by formula from Contact Data). I am going to add these in the sample for testing

I added them to the sample, they all match, but not in the actual. I will keep chipping at it. If you have any ideas awesome, if not totally understandable since I can't seem to recreate the issue.
